# Titanium studio variables don't change on view

Tags: javascript, variables, titanium

I am new to Titanium and am trying to display a variable stored in my Titanium properties into a view page with this code:

```
var display = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : storedVariable,
    color : 'black',
    font : {fontSize:12},
    height : 15,
    width : 250,
    top : '10%',
    left : '10%',
    textAlign : 'center'
});
```

The problem I have is I am changing `storedVarible` in a different page but it only changes in the display when I restart the app.

I need the variable to update as soon as I change it. I scoured the Titanium pages and stack exchange but couldn't find any answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `Ti.UI.createLabel()` is called only once. To update the text value, you can create a new function that will reset the text property of your label:

```
function updateLabelText(newText){
    display.text = newText;
}
```

Then each time `storedVariable` changes, you can call `updateLabelText(storedVariable);`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `storedVariable` is being passed to the object/instance on its creation: that is to say, the value of it is only used when you create the UI Label instance `display`. Therefore `display.text` would not change in real time if you just give `storedVariable` a new value after `display`'s creation.

What you are doing is similar to having

```
var b = 10;

var a = b;

b = 5;
```

`a` would still be 10 even if you assign 5 to `b`.

Instead of changing the value of `storedVariable`, you need to change the value of `display.text`.